# Changing the base artifact for gradle plugins

Tags: gradle, plugins, artifactory

We have built a gradle plugin using

```
id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.15.0" 
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.16" 
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
```

This is getting picked up by the central maven but we want it to be from the artifactory that we provide or from the local system path where I have downloaded the pom. Any leads will be appreciated.

We have tried using the below code but to no avail:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url=uri("url")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle searches for plugins defined inside the `plugins` block in repositories that are defined in the `pluginManagement` block of the `settings.gradle.kts` file ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories)).

For example:

```
// settings.gradle.kts

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        // define any other repositories you like, eg
        maven { // details of own Maven repo }
        gradlePluginPortal() // The default setting, but must be re-specified if using this block if you still want to use it
    }
}
```

Comment: We have tried this as well Simon, we still get the same error as Plugin[ details ] was not found in any of the following sources.

Comment: You need to make sure you are publishing your plugins properly. They follow a slightly different convention to Maven artifacts. Ensure you are using the java-gradle-plugin to publish a class-based plugin.

Comment: We have tried the same, also the plugins are already published by the organisation in JFrog so that wont be an issue.